# Ubuntu 16.04 - Wifi hard blocked in Acer ES1-521 laptop

Tags: wireless, ath9k

I am a newbie to Ubuntu and installed Ubuntu 16.04 in my Acer ES1-521 laptop. WiFi worked right after the installation, but now i see Wireless adapter is hard blocked.

Machine has a Qualcomm Atheros 9565 card. There is no switch to turn off/on wifi. Only the Fn + F3.

Seems the hard block started after i switched off and on bluetooth. Not sure it caused it or just a coincidence.

I had tried the following to remove hard unblock.

rfkill unblock all
modprobe ath9k
Bios reset (F9) - Wifi card works just fine in Windows 10 before and after bios reset

None of the above could unblock wifi.

any other suggestions please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with Acer ES1-521 laptop. Following [Link here](https://superuser.com/questions/1138978/acer-aspire-es1-521-cannot-turn-on-wifi-after-switch-to-linux), I did the following and it worked fine.

```
blacklist acer-wmi
```

to my `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`. Then a quick reboot and wireless network detected and working fine from then on.